# How to start a function at specific row

Tags: r, database, function

I have a sport dataset which have:
ID1, ID2, DAYS, RESULT (0 for lost, 1 is match won)

I've created a function that show previous result for ID1 and ID2 at the time the match occurred. I would like to run this function only to a certain range of rows or last 20 rows. I thought that command head and tail could be usefull but don't know how. Maybe create a loop?

Any help would be appreciated

reproducibile example of dataset and functions

```
 t <-structure(list(ID1 = c(29833, 17264, 29469, 30795, 32243, 4025, 
37004, 15021, 25539, 28992, 12767, 25172, 4088, 27777, 10500, 25703, 
24843, 27185, 28742, 28762, 23461, 4025, 35036, 25539, 28992, 47557, 
23142, 28742, 29469, 25539, 28992, 23142, 4025, 15021, 1569, 26923, 
27111, 29939, 39309, 4964, 6831, 26221, 12430, 20104, 12653, 6817, 
18648, 26059, 520, 6528, 10014, 10202, 20648, 14606, 14716, 11981, 
6850, 25095, 58865, 13267, 23299, 27114, 10920, 39900, 22949, 34707, 
39898, 27012, 24877, 19942), 

ID2 = c(28742, 28762, 19877, 19946, 28077, 8858, 10404, 27778, 38071, 
24945, 29149, 29257, 35036, 47557, 34915, 23142, 30795, 14477, 14534, 
29469, 34537, 32243, 15021, 10404, 29257, 29149, 27185, 34537, 24843, 
15021, 29149, 28742, 29469, 29149, 24225, 1181, 3996, 17005, 9043, 
12661, 18485, 9842, 11521, 12495, 12852, 13048, 27783, 13348, 13032, 
13820, 775, 25082, 10813, 11373, 10415, 427, 4454, 9094, 11815, 58864, 
58863, 25104, 34064, 19689, 39901, 34920, 58866, 8396, 16996, 28087), 

DAYS = c(4013, 4013, 4013, 4013, 4013, 4013, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 
4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014, 4014,
 4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 4016, 4016, 4016, 4016, 4017,
 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 
4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017,
 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017, 4017), 

RESULT = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame")

PREV_WIN_LAST10 <-function(id1,days){
  rang=60
  s1 <- subset(t, ID1 == id1, select=c(ID1,RESULT,DAYS))
  s1 <- subset(s1, DAYS < days)
  s1 <- subset(s1, DAYS > (days-rang))
  s12 <- subset(t, ID2 == id1, select=c(ID2,RESULT,DAYS))
  s12 <- subset(s12, DAYS < days)
  s12 <- subset(s12, DAYS > (days-rang))
  s12$RESULT <- ifelse(s12$RESULT == 0,1,0)
  names(s12)[names(s12) == 'ID2'] <- 'ID1'
  s <- rbind(s1, s12)
  s<-tail(s, n=10)
  s<-s[complete.cases(s), ] #ELIMINA I NAN (è uguale a na.omit)
  return(tryCatch(nrow(s[s$RESULT==1,]), error=function(e) NaN))
}
t$WIN1PREV_7_A <- unlist(mapply(PREV_WIN_LAST10, t$ID1, t$DAYS))
t$WIN2PREV_7_A <- unlist(mapply(PREV_WIN_LAST10, t$ID2, t$DAYS))
```

Expected output:

I want to run the function WIN1PREV_7_A only to the last 20 rows of dataset (for example), not all the data.

Comment: what is your expected output? What does `WIN1PREV_7_A` and `WIN2PREV_7_A` represent ?

Comment: WIN1PREV is a function that returns how many  match won by ID1 and ID2.

Every week I have to update the statics with new matches (it means adding new rows) and it's a waste of time repeat functions  that I've already run before. I would like to run functions in a certain range of rows and not all the dataset

Comment: It's not clear to me how is `WIN1PREV_7_A` calculated? How do you know which of `ID1` or `ID2` has won the match? What does `DAYS` supposed to mean? Can you explain in words what `PREV_WIN_LAST10` function is currently doing instead of we debugging and understanding your code? And finally can you show us the output that you expect for the given data `t` ?

Comment: never mind, I found a way. A simple ifelse in the function do the job. 
thanx anyway